# MongoDB - query output changes using different values

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

okay so im trying to return a single object that is stored in an array. i am getting the information from the DB using a req.params here is some working code:

```
router
    .route("/book-review/:book")
    .get((req, res) => {
        return model.findById(req.user.id).select({
            'posts': {
                $elemMatch: {
                    "title": req.params.book
                }
            }
        })
```

this one returns :

```
{
    _id: 5ae1be4c48c5360c5457da48,
    posts: [
               {
                   i: 5ae21180bb811e1a453317f0,
                   title: 'cc',
                   chapters: []
                }
           ]
 }
```

this returns exactly what i want it returns a single object stored in the post array however because the url(when using title) may have the same value as another post title this is a problem and i want to use a ObjectID (which i have setup)

```
router
     .route("/book-review/:book")
     .get((req, res) => {
        return model.findById(req.user.id).select({
            'posts': {
                $elemMatch: {
                    "i": req.params.book
                }
            }
        })
```

when i change it from the "title" to "i" (this store the individual posts id) it returns a whole different value this one returns just this:

```
{
    _id: 5ae1be4c48c5360c5457da48
}
```

(this is the parent ObjectId as you can see above when using title)

can someone explain what is at play here and how i can get the first result without using title an using an id instead?

Comment: you have renamed '_id' field as 'i' is it?

Comment: no each user has its own _id but each object in post array has one of its own ids also stored in "i"

Comment: you are passing req.params.book to query that has 'title' and also you pass the same req.params.book to the query that has 'i' . why are you doing this?

Comment: no i am changing how i am querying it. im not querying both at the same time